# Trying to change multiple files' extensions

Tags: find, rename

Using the command line (in Fedora) I'd like to rename all the files in the current directory, that have "foo" for the extension, to the same name but with foo1 for the extension.

I've tried several examples found on StackExchange:

```
rename foo foo1 *.foo
```

and

```
find . -name '*.foo' -execdir rename 's/\.foo$/.foo1/' \{} \;
```

Both generate the following error multiple times:

```
rename: not enough arguments
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of just `find . -name '*.foo'`? Your `not enough arguments` may be from the fact that `*.foo` expands to nothing (no files match that pattern) so rename complains because you only gave it 1 args.

Comment: You also may want to check `man rename`. Not all renames work that way. The `rename` on Debian stretch expects a perl expression and a list of files to apply it to: `rename 's/\e.foo$/foo1/' *.foo`

Comment: That does seem to be the error message you'd get from the `util-linux` "version" of `rename` (known as `rename.ul` on some systems) when `*.foo` expands to nothing - although in many shells, that would require non-default globbing behavior (bash `shopt -s nullglob` or zsh `setopt null_glob` for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `rename` might not work everywhere. Another way to achieve this is to use `find`, `mv`, and some bash substitution.

```
find . -name '*.foo' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.foo}.foo1"' "{}" \;
```

A few things to note:

I use `-exec` and not `-execdir`. The latter effectively `cd`s to the directory of the matched file (which isn't what you want, because then the path to the file--which will be relative to `.`--will no longer be correct). You want just `-exec` which will run the given command for each file that matches `-name '*.foo'` (replacing `{}` with the path to the matched file).

`"${0%.foo}"` strips the extension `.foo` so if `$0` is `"hello.foo"` then `"${0%.foo}"` ends up as `"hello"`. Then adding `.foo1` to the end just appends that, so `"${0%.foo}.foo1"` is `"hello.foo1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop

```
for f in *.foo
do
    mv $f ${f/.foo/.foo1}
done
```

Comment: This would rename a file called `file.foo-something.foo` to `file.foo1-something.foo`. Better to use `"${f%.foo}.foo1"`.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda.  However, your pattern changed `foo.foo-x` to `foo.foo-x.foo1`.  Also, the use of `for` loop will eliminate the files that do not end in `.foo`.

Comment: I took your loop into account. It would not process a file called `foo.foo-x`. My example in my comment does end with `.foo` though.

Comment: OP said "I'd like to rename all the files in the current directory, that have "foo" for the extension, to the same name but with foo1 for the extension."

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `1` to the name of all files whose name originally end with `.foo`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.foo' -exec mv -i {} {}1 ';'
```